# Jruby trying to load local ruby gems instead of packaged ones

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I'm seeing a weird issue in my jruby jar and I'm sure it's due to some configuration but I can't quite figure out what. The behavior I'm seeing is when my jruby jar goes to load a gem it looks for it in my local ruby envrionment instead of inside the jar itself. If I move my jar to a system that does not have a ruby envrionment then it uses the gems packaged in the jar.

Here is my boot rb file.

```
require 'rubygems'
app_jar_root = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), ".."))

Dir["#{app_jar_root}/Project/**/*/"].each do |foldername|
  $LOAD_PATH.unshift foldername[-1] == '/' ? foldername[0..-2] : foldername
end


# All support libraries required to be included
[
  'java',
  'yaml'
].each do |require_name|
  require require_name
end

# All java imported namespaces
[
   # 'java.sql.DriverManager'
].each do |namespace|
  java_import namespace
end

# base app directory requires
Dir["#{app_jar_root}/Project/app/**/*.rb"].reject do |filename|
  %w|file_to_exclude1.rb file_to_exclude2|.include? File.basename(filename)
end.each do |filename|
  require File.basename(filename)
end

# Debugger.start
```

I can also post my warble.rb if that would be of any use but I'm assuming the issue is some configuration in boot.rb.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was that my jruby jar was referencing the local `GEM_PATH` and `GEM_HOME`variables if they existed on a system. To fix this I had to redirect the variables to point inside the jar by reassigning them in the `boot.rb` file.

Here's an example of how I achieved this where `app_jar_root` is the root of the app folder in the jar.

```
ENV['GEM_HOME'] = "#{app_jar_root}/gems"
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = "#{app_jar_root}/gems"
```